# Redirecting http to https using nginx behind AWS load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, nginx, https, network-protocols

I've searched high and low and I feel this is the final hurdle for my project. I'm trying to redirect all http traffic to https.

Currently when typing domain.info, it redirects to https://domain.info:80 and returns ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

But replacing the 80 with 443 gives me my webpage just fine.

My server is behind a load balancer too, I have my certificates in the LB and none in my server. I'm using NGINX as my webserver. Basically this is my setup:

user>https>load balancer>http>server

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, catch all HTTP incoming:

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name _;
   return ....;
}
```

2. then redirect to HTTPS permanently

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name _;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

or...

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name foo.com;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name foo.com;
}
```

Comment: Please consider referencing sources when grabbing info off the internet: https://serversforhackers.com/c/redirect-http-to-https-nginx

Comment: Generally, the load blancer handles SSL and redirects everything to HTTP.
So nginx can't receive https connections directly

Answer (score 0):

Directly in the load balancer, you can add a redirection rule, did you try to play with that?

In the load balancer listener, update the default rule for HTTP:80 and configure it like this :

```
HTTP 80: default action
IF
Requests otherwise not routed
THEN
Redirect to https://#{host}:443/#{path}?#{query}
Status code:HTTP_301
```

Comment: yeah, I have that set up. It gave an infinite redirect loop i.e. "too many redirects"

Comment: Probably because you also have a redirection rule in your nginx configuration, simply remove this redirection rule in nginx should fix this problem.

Comment: HTTP 301 is flawed, what if I want HTTP 307/308 redirect ?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by 301 is flawed. I used it from many years without any problem. if it don't work it probably come from somewhere else. Otherwise, in the aws load balancer listener, you can choose between 301 or 302 status code, don't look like they handle the 307 and 308 status code here. So if you need these status code, this solution may not be for you.